# How can plot line graph for each country that takes place in the column?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to plot three lines for Turkey, the UK and OECD through the years but those countries are not columns so I am suffering finding a way plot them.

I get this df via

> df = df.loc[df["Variable"].eq("Relative advantage")
> & df["Country"].isin(["United Kingdom", "Türkiye", "OECD - Total"])]

| Year | Country | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1990 | Turkiye | 20 |
| 1980 | UK | 34 |
| 1992 | UK | 32 |
| 1980 | OECD | 29 |
| 1992 | OECD | 23 |

Comment: please share the data not as the picture. moreover share the data all of all countries and your tries (share the code).

Comment: I hope now it is better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pivot_table() method to do this. An example:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Set up example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1990,'Turkiye',20],
    [1992,'Turkiye',22],
    [1990,'UK',34],
    [1992,'UK',32],
    [1990,'OECD',29],
    [1992,'OECD',23],
], columns=["year", "country", "value"])

# Pivot so countries are now columns
table = df.pivot_table(values='value', columns='country', index='year')
```

This creates a dataframe where the countries are columns:

```
country  OECD  Turkiye  UK
year                      
1990       29       20  34
1992       23       22  32
```

(I changed some of the dates to make it work out a bit more nicely.)

Then I plot it:

[image: plot of fictional data for three countries]